# Same probability distribution for monthly/yearly data?

Tags: probability, distributions, weights

I don't know if this is the right forum to ask this, but anyway.

I don't have enough yearly data to perform a study on. Suppose I put weights on my monthly data to transform the monthly data into yearly data so the monthly data is now yearly frequencies instead of monthly frequencies.

Is it possible to assume that these monthly observation is drawn from the same probability distribution as if they were yearly frequencies?
If I want study what happens one time in 100 years, is it reasonable to assume that the probability distribution will be approximately the same as study the one time in 100 months, just with different weights?

My question is maybe delivered quite poorly, I don't really know how to explain it in other ways. But the yearly observation is just a sum of the monthly observation which is a sum of daily observations and so on, my thought were that they must follow some kind of similar distribution just with different weigths.

Would be glad if someone could tell me if I am completely wrong or not...

Comment: Could you tell us more about your data? If you don't have enough data, aggregating it would not give you more, but fewer, data points. If yearly data is the sum, then you don't need to weight the months, just sum them.

Comment: So I want to study the probability of a customer leaving the company. We don't have enough yearly observations. There is a regulatory framework that says we have to count the risk of a 100-year scenario. If I use the probability of leaving each month instead of each year, but put weights on these monthly observations so that the months represent yearly observation will the probability distribution approximately be the same as the underlying process would be the approximately the same for each observation? Is a 100-year scenario approximately a 100 month scenario just with different weights?

Comment: No, it isn't. You cannot "create" yearly data from monthly data. Imagine another example: your aim is to forecast ice cream sales over the year, but you have only a few weeks of data from the winter, could you extrapolate from this data to forecast summer sales?

Comment: I mean the underlying process that "dealing" with customers leaving the company should be the same regardless if I study the monthly observations or the yearly observations and therefore the probability distribution. So if I use 10 years data but instead use each month so I get 120 months instead of 10 years. If I transform it into yearly observations by putting weights on it, if I fit a probability distribution to it, is it possible to assume that this fitted distribution will also be the case if i hade 120 yearly data instead of using months.. Hope you understand!

Comment: But in that case the underlying process is not the same for ice cream sales during winter and during summer?

Comment: The underlying process of buying ice cream is that it's hot so cold ice cream feels nice. If it is cold outside, in most cases you don't have the need to eat something cold. The process is not the same and I can assure you that the sales of ice cream in the summer is much higher than in the winter.

Answer (score 0):

> If I want study what happens one time in 100 years, is it reasonable to assume that the probability distribution will be approximately the same as study the one time in 100 months, just with different weights?

No, it isn't. If during 100 months I didn't need to replace the electric installation in my house, does this mean that I wouldn't need to do it over 100 years? If during the last 100 months I didn't die, would I live for the next 100 years? If there wasn't a [100-year flood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/100-year_flood) during the last 100 months, does this mean that there wouldn't be any during 100 years' time?

If you need to make a 100-year prediction, the reason is probably that it needs to account for long-term events or rare events. If your data is about customers leaving the company, then during the next 100 years many of the customers you have right now would be dead, it already makes the data slightly irrelevant. But that's not all, things in the next 100 years would likely be quite different than nowadays. There are also things that need time, for example, people rarely change cars every few months, but it would be way more likely to happen after several years.

That said, it doesn't mean that such analysis is not possible, it's just *much* more complicated. You can read about [predicting 100-year floods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/100-year_flood) or about [extreme value theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theory) that is used for such problems. I am *not* going to try to give a more detailed answer because you are dealing with a hard problem, where the details may make a huge difference in the methodology and the results. If you need to do this for regulatory reasons and don't know how, if I were you I'd hire an expert consultant to help you, as doing it poorly likely can have negative legal consequences for your company.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! I'm aware of the EVT, the problem is the amount of yearly data as we got 40 years of data to predict the 100-year event.